# strerror_r is incorrectly declared on Alpine Linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, alpine-linux

I'm using [strerror_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r) in a logging helper function.  As the man page describes, there are two versions of this function.  The POSIX version returns an int.  The GNU version returns a string (char*).

As such, so that my C++ code is more portable, I have a block of code similar to this:

```
    char buffer[1000];
    int size = 1000;
    int result = 0;
    char* msg = buffer;
    buffer[0] = '\0';
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
    msg = strerror_r(err, buffer, size);
#else
    result = strerror_r(err, buffer, size);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "unknown error: %d", err);
    }
#endif
    LogToFile(msg);
```

In the above code block, it will use either version of `strerror_r` depending on the presence of `_GNU_SOURCE`, which is ALWAYS set by g++ because libstdc++ requires it.  On Mac, and other variations of Unix, it will use the POSIX version.

Now this code has been working out well for a long time until today.  A user trying to compile my code on [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/) and reported this compiler error today on the line using `strerror_r`

```
main.cpp:16:21 error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Which maps to this line:

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
    msg = strerror_r(err, buffer, size);
```

Taking a peak at the `/usr/include/string.h` on this platform reveals the following:

```
#if defined(_POSIX_SOURCE) || defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) \
 || defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) || defined(_GNU_SOURCE) \
 || defined(_BSD_SOURCE)
...
int strerror_r (int, char *, size_t);
...
#endif
```

Which appears that no matter what compiler environment is used, the only declared version of strerror_r is the POSIX version that returns an int.  So that explains why the error occurred.

Without having to tell users that they can manually `#undef _GNU_SOURCE` or modify the source, how can I work around this such that the code can continue to be portable?  Globally undefining _GNU_SOURCE is likely a non-starter because this is C++ (and as mentioned above, required by libstdc++).  I'm trying to see if there would be another macro combination that I could test for, but I'm not able to come up with anything obvious.

Comment: The official macro check (according to the manual page you link to) is `(_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE` to be true if the POSIX version is provided, else the GNU version is provided. That means your check should be enough to make sure the GNU version is provided, and the C library in Alpine Linux seems to be buggy or outdated.

Comment: Wrap it in your own function. Make it flexible enough to use either variant.

Comment: @n.m. Can you elaborate?  It's already wrapped in a function...

Comment: C++ is powerful enough to decide which version of the function to use without any help from macros. Think function overloading.

Comment: The C library on Alpine Linux is musl and it's up-to-date, if you use up-to-date Alpine release.

Comment: @JakubJirutka - Am using latest Alpine Linux.  musl's use of the posix version of strerror_r is in conflict with what the man page says on how to test for which version to use.  g++ compiler always sets _GNU_SOURCE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take advantage of C++ function overloading:

```
char* check_error(int result, char* buffer, int err) {
    if(result)
        sprintf(buffer, "unknown error: %d", err);
    return buffer;
}

char* check_error(char* result, char*, int) {
    return result;
}
```

And and get rid of conditional compilation in the usage:

```
char buffer[1000];
buffer[0] = '\0';
char* msg = check_error(strerror_r(err, buffer, sizeof buffer), buffer, err);
LogToFile(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I didn't think of this myself.  Seems so obvious now.